Pitch and formants of vowels of female singer voice
I am looking data on female singing voice that contains
(pitch F0), F1, F2, (possibly more formants)
for phonetic vowels 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', (possibly more vowels)
when sung at different keys 4th octave - 5th octave (possibly more).
Any suggestions for links / sources are welcome.
Thank you.
